# Giving system error please try again letter (id 520002) in iOS when trying to pay US customer with paypal

Tags: ios, paypal

I successfully integrated PayPal MPL library in ios. And working perfectly . But when i try to pay to the US client it gives error "System error.Please try again letter .(ID 520002)". I am using this code to make payment.

```
PayPal *ppMEP = [PayPal getPayPalInst];
ppMEP.shippingEnabled = true;
ppMEP.dynamicAmountUpdateEnabled = TRUE;
ppMEP.feePayer = FEEPAYER_EACHRECEIVER;
ppMEP.delegate=self;
PayPalPayment *currentPayment = [[PayPalPayment alloc] init];
currentPayment.paymentCurrency = @"USD";
currentPayment.paymentType = TYPE_SERVICE;
currentPayment.subTotal = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[NSString        
currentPayment.recipient =recipientString;
currentPayment.merchantName = [NSStringstringWithFormat:@"%@xxxRoyalties%@",merchantNameString,setMonthsButtonTitle];
[ppMEP checkoutWithPayment:currentPayment];
```

I also attach the a pic of error.

Answer (score 1):

After lot of google search and some conversion with PayPal I found that it is bug. internal error with description message **INTERNAL_ERROR&message=Invalid payload size. current payload size=215756, max payload size=204800**. The person using MPL can use new iOS SDK . It works fine all over the places where the MPL PayPal library is working . Direct card facility is only available in US UK and CA only.

Comment: I'm getting the same error using the MPL library with chained payments. I'm still unclear on how you worked around the issue.